Reverse Engineering SE - Not Yet Ready For Public Beta
Update:
You've come together and have all done a great job on getting this site defined, Reverse Engineering SE will progress to a public beta in the near future.
Congratulations, and please keep up the good work!

We've got quite a bit of work to do before we progress to a public beta.
Reverse Engineering had an amazing show of support during its Area 51 commitment phase , where 351 people expressed their support and enthusiasm for the site and committed to help make it a success.
Out of those that committed, less than half (164, or 47%) signed up for the site within the first few days of private beta. After a reminder was sent out, an additional 135 users signed up. We have 299 users now, but almost half arrived late to the party. We're concerned that some might have been showing their support for the site, but weren't especially interested in helping it launch. We hope we're wrong.
The site has only 69 questions, 62 of which are currently open. The purpose of the initial week long private beta is to prepare the site for public consumption; a lot of very important things need to happen in this phase:

At least 80-ish questions that this community feels are exemplary questions about reverse engineering need to be asked. Remember, don't ask questions just to seed content, try to come up with real-world challenging questions that will catch people's attention and demonstrate that these questions deserve their own home. If most of the 300 people who signed up ask even one great question, then we'll have quite a site to unveil.

Important discussions need to be raised on your Meta forum. During the private beta phase, it's critical that you ask and discuss the 7-essential questions every beta needs to ask. You've discussed a few, but questions like what your FAQ should contain need to be discussed before the site is open to the public. We need to see more input here.

Expanding on the need to establish your FAQ, the question of what it should contain implies starting additional discussions of what is and is not on topic for your site. Some topic discussions have been raised, but haven't received very much attention. We hope to see more participation on your meta forum overall.


We're going to extend your private beta period for another week, allowing folks that arrived very recently to get involved and start contributing to the site. In the meantime, don't forget that you can invite more people to your private beta if you feel that they would be strong contributors. Use the form on the right side bar of your home page:

Remember, you want a front page full of exemplary questions that would entice any expert in reverse engineering to explore and hopefully join the site. If you know someone that is doing interesting work in the field and might have some tough questions to ask, or can answer some tough questions themselves - don't hesitate to invite them.

Is there a numerical SE definition for exemplary ?

@AshRj By exemplary, I mean questions that your community feels are excellent, and that experts in the field would find enticing. As I've indicated that we really need more questions, it would be somewhat irresponsible of me not to point out that the questions are the public face of the site. Just try your best to come up with interesting questions that will draw people in.

@TimPost: I for one hadn't seen it on Area51 and was instead invited. Did you distinguish that case in the stats or not?

@TimPost: as for the FAQ I have input to share, but I am unsure whether to edit the existing CW post or write my own!

@0xC0000022L You can add your own initially, which can be edited in afterward. If you think it may need a little discussion in comments first, it's probably better to just add an answer.
